# How To Search The TableviewData in Different ViewController?

Tags: ios, xcode, uisearchdisplaycontroller, searchbar

I have a NewsViewController where News Displaying Form XML , My Problem is I Created Separate Class Called SearchVC and I have Added the Search Bar, Here I want search the all the News 
(from NewsViewController). The Search Result Should Display in the  Drop down List, If i click those Search result It should Redirect to the NewsDetailsViewController. I do not know how to do this can any one help me out of this issue .

Here is my NewsViewController.m

```
#import "NewsViewController.h"
#import "NewsTableViewCell.h"
#import "NewDetailsViewController.h"
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
@interface NewsViewController ()
{
    NSString *temString;
    NSMutableString *strTemp;
}

@end

@implementation NewsViewController
@synthesize arrImages;
@synthesize TittleOne;
@synthesize TittleTwo;
@synthesize TittleThree;
@synthesize datepicker;
@synthesize PickerContainer;
@synthesize datepickerTittle;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - View Life Cycle
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [TittleOne setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"GEEast-ExtraBold" size:12]];
    [TittleTwo setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"GEEast-ExtraBold" size:10]];
      [TittleThree setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"GEEast-ExtraBold" size:10]];
   // [[UIColor redColor] set];
    [datepickerTittle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"GEEast-ExtraBold" size:12]];
   // [datepickerTittle.textColor= [UIColor yellowColor]];


    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.arrTitles =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.arrDescription=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.arrImages=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.arrDate=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.arrUrls=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    //[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(requestingForNews:) withObject:nil];

   // dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), s^{
    self.spinnerView.hidden=NO;
        [self makeRequestForNews];
  //  self.spinnerView.stopAnimating;
    //});

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self imagedownloader:@"http://www.shura.bh/MediaCenter/News/"];
}
-(void)requestingForNews:(id)sender
{
     [self makeRequestForNews];
}
-(void) imagedownloader : (NSString *)urlStringOfImage
{
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    //downlaod image
        NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStringOfImage];
        NSData  *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50 )];
            imageView.image = image;
            [self.view addSubview:imageView];
        });
    });
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma  mark - make request for news
-(void)makeRequestForNews
{

    NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:self.strNewsApi];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    //After making request the apparent thing is expecting the response that may be expected response or an Error. so create those objects and intialize them with NULL.
    NSURLResponse *response = NULL;
    NSError *requestError =NULL;
    //Once you have response with you , Capture YOur Responce data using NsData.

    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&requestError];

    //Convert the respnse Data into Response String.

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //Now We can start parsing the Data using XMl parser . you need XML parser in-order to use the below class method "dictionaryFOrXMLString".

    NSError *parserError = NULL;

    //XML parsing

    NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:responseData];
    [xmlParser setDelegate:self];
    [xmlParser parse];

//    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
//    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
//    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

  //NSDictionary *xmlDict = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:responseString error:NULL];

    //once you have xmlDict handy, you can pass this to the any ViewController (Like table view) to populate the Data.
}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{


    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"ShuraNews"])
    {

    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"PUBLISHINGPAGEIMAGE"])
    {

    }
    strTemp=[NSMutableString new];
}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    //temString =string;
    [strTemp appendString:string];
}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"TITLE"])
    {
        NSLog(@"temstring=== %@", strTemp);
        [self.arrTitles addObject:strTemp];
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"PUBLISHINGPAGECONTENT"])
    {
        NSLog(@"temstring=== %@", strTemp);
        [self.arrDescription addObject:strTemp];
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"NEWSARTICLEDATE"])
    {
        NSLog(@"temstring=== %@", strTemp);
        [self.arrDate addObject:strTemp];
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"PUBLISHINGPAGEIMAGE"])
    {

        NSLog(@"temstring=== %@", strTemp);
        [self.arrImages addObject:strTemp];
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"ShuraNews"])
    {
        [self.tblNews reloadData];
       // self.spinnerView.hidden=YES;
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"URL"])
    {
        [self.arrUrls addObject:strTemp];
    }

}

#pragma mark - TabeView Datasource//delegate method

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.arrTitles count];
//
//    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
//    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
//    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd mmm yyyy"];
//    [datepicker sortUsingComparator:^(id dateObje1,id dateObje2)
//     {
//         NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[(datepicker) dateObje1 arrDate]];
//         NSDate *date2 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[(datepicker) dateObje2 arrDate]];
//         return [date2 compare:date1];
//    }
//     ];

}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"cellNews";
    NewsTableViewCell *cell=(NewsTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[NewsTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        // cell.NewsTableViewCell.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x000000);
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        //SDWebImage Code for lazy loader
        [cell.imgNews setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.arrImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.gif"]];
    }

    if( [indexPath row] % 2){
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor =UIColorFromRGB(0Xffffff);

    }
    else{
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor =UIColorFromRGB (0Xdcdcdc);
    }

  //selectbackground color start
    UIView *NewsTableViewCell = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
    NewsTableViewCell.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0Xdcdcdc);
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = NewsTableViewCell; //select background colro end
    cell.lblTitles.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"GEEast-ExtraBold" size:12];
    cell.lblTitles.text=[self.arrTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lblDescription.font =[UIFont fontWithName:@"GE SS Unique" size:12];
    cell.lblDate.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"GE SS Unique" size:12];
    cell.lblDescription.text=[self.arrDescription objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lblDate.text=[self.arrDate objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lblTitles.textAlignment= NSTextAlignmentRight;
    cell.lblDate.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    cell.lblDescription.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    //cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[arrImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.arrImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
    cell.imgNews.image=[UIImage imageWithData:data];
    cell.imgNews.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    cell.imgNews.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
    [PickerContainer setHidden:YES];
    if (!cell.imgNews.image)
    {
        cell.lblTitles.frame=CGRectMake(cell.lblTitles.frame.origin.x, cell.lblTitles.frame.origin.y, 283, cell.lblTitles.frame.size.height);
        cell.lblDate.frame=CGRectMake(cell.lblDate.frame.origin.x, cell.lblDate.frame.origin.y, 286, cell.lblDate.frame.size.height);
        cell.lblDescription.frame=CGRectMake(cell.lblDescription.frame.origin.x, cell.lblDescription.frame.origin.y, 281, cell.lblDescription.frame.size.height);
        cell.imgNews.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        cell.imgNews.layer.borderWidth = 0;
           }
 return cell;
}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        NSDictionary *dict=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
        [self.arrTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]],@"title",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
        [self.arrImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]],@"img",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
        [self.arrDescription objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]],@"Des",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.arrUrls objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]],@"url", nil];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"NewsDetailsID" sender:dict];

}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"NewsDetailsID"])
    {
        ((NewDetailsViewController *)segue.destinationViewController).strTitle=[sender objectForKey:@"title"];
         ((NewDetailsViewController *)segue.destinationViewController).strDetailImage=[sender objectForKey:@"img"];
        ((NewDetailsViewController *)segue.destinationViewController).strDescription=[sender objectForKey:@"Des"];//strUrl
          ((NewDetailsViewController *)segue.destinationViewController).strUrl=[sender objectForKey:@"url"];
    }
}

- (IBAction)backBtnClicked:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


@end
```

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as searching is concerned, You'll have to search your arrays in the `NewsViewController`, based on keywords that the user enters and if any results are returned, the perform a segue to your `NewsDetailsViewController` where those results will be displayed. For performing segue to the `NewsDetailsViewController`, you can use this method,

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueIdentifier" sender:nil];
```

Another suggestion is to use `UITableViewController` instead of Dropdown. The reason being that it is available in the SDK itself and you can show somewhat more data using TableView whereas Dropdown has to be made custom.

Comment: Ok Thanks for your answer .. Ill try this .If possible can you provide me any example Tutorial to get Some Basic Idea ...

Comment: Glad that it helped you. And which tutorial are you talking about ? A `UITableViewController` tutorial ?

Comment: Thank you very much for first Answer .  Yes i want look in to   UITableViewController tutorial too  . can you please ?